# What happens when Front ==rear in circular queue

Tags: data-structures, queue

What happens when front==rear in circular queue

is queue have one element or is full or is empty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's ambiguous.  You need another mechanism to track whether the queue is full.  See the Difficulties section on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) for a discussion.

To quote from that page, here are some ideas on how to solve it:

> To solve this problem there are a
>   number of solutions:
>   - Always keep one slot open.
>   - Use a fill count to distinguish the two cases.
>   - Use read and write counts to get the fill count from. 
>   - Use absolute indices

.

Comment: I am asking that what happens if the front and rear are equal in the queue
i.e in the queue of length 5
if rear stars from -1 and front starts from 0 then if (front==rear)
what happens..

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where front and rear are pointing at: array elements, or objects somewhere on the heap. (You didn't mention your programming language.)

If in your programming language `nil` doesn't equal `nil`, your circular queue of objects will have one element. But if `nil == nil` evaluates to `true`... you can't tell :-)

In the case of a queue implemented via an array, you can't tell it either. Your queue may be full as well...